# Unix shell script - mailsend

Tags: email, unix

I'm trying to execute an Unix shell script to generate emails using `mailsend`. I need to format this as an HTML file using it's content type

My script as follows,

```
sender="xxxx@xxxx.com"
subject="My Subject"
server=000.000.000.000
message=`cat fun.txt`
email_add="test@test.com"
nohup ./mailsend -f $sender -t $email_add -u "$subject" -m "$message" -s $server
  -l fcbulog
```

How can I achieve the HTML formatted email by using above script

Answer (score 0):

You could set `Content-Type` to `text/html` and then just use the your html as body of the message.